# Are the Yoruba and Japanese pantheons the only ones to have an infinite increasing number of gods?

Tags: comparative, japanese, pantheon, yoruba

I know that the Yoruba and Japanese gods have basically an infinite number of gods since their pantheons continue to grow all the time but are there any other pantheons that do this?

Comment: Many polytheistic religions have an unlimited number of gods. Hindu and Chinese come to mind.

Comment: Japanese *kami* is theoretically infinite but the pantheon of major deities isn't constantly growing. I'm not sure where you can draw the line on this. For example Graeco-Roman mythology allows for mortals to be deified, so does that not count as theoretically infinitely increasing gods?

Comment: @Semaphore So the famous gods don't, it's just the unlimited minor ones that are constantly growing in number?

Comment: I think it is hard to define the main pantheon for any mythology if it is not self-established by the myths themselves.

Comment: And a lot of myths are inconsistent.

Comment: @Mauricio I know the Japanese use the number 8 million to express unlimited amount of gods

Comment: Could you define what you mean by pantheon? If by that you mean the entirety of all deities within a mythology, then most of them have an unlimited number of gods.

Comment: @Orionixe it's more accurate to translate *kami* as spirits. "8 million kami" is an expressing denoting that the spirits are multitudinous, because in Japanese cosmology, everything from the winds to the roads can have a spirit. It's not really clear that the total number of spirits are actually increasing, or if the objects are playing host to some aspect of divinity, or that there are infinite spirits.

Comment: @Semaphore I asked my Japanese friend and he said 8 million represents unlimited amount, so I'm not sure

Comment: @Mauricio what do you mean by most of them?

Comment: Most= every polytheistic mythologies/religions with a large range of different types of deities

Comment: @Mauricio They have unlimited?

Comment: Example: There are about 3000-4000 registered deities in Greek mythology, if any of them have an offspring from another god then you have one more god and so on. You can also have mortals be converted into gods.

Comment: If 8 million is already a surprising number, look for Hindu deities, the total number is estimated to be about 33 million.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133522/discussion-between-orionixe-and-mauricio).